# Firefox won't submit a form created by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox3.6

I need to create a form with a few inputs when an event happens. My code is below.

Chrome submits fine - the alert box shows and the page changes.

Firefox does not work - the alert box shows but the page stays the same. **How can I get Firefox to submit the form?**

```
var idsInput = document.createElement('input');
idsInput.name = 'itemIds';
idsInput.value = ids;

var quantityInput = document.createElement('input');;
quantityInput.name = 'quantity';
quantityInput.value = 1;

var authTokenInput = document.createElement('input');
authTokenInput.name = 'authenticityToken';
authTokenInput.value = '${session.getAuthenticityToken()}';

var submitInput = document.createElement('input');
submitInput.type = 'submit';
submitInput.value = 'anything';

var form = document.createElement('form');;
form.action = '@{Checkout.setItemsQuantityHandler}';
form.method = 'POST';
form.elements[0] = idsInput;
form.elements[1] = quantityInput;
form.elements[2] = authTokenInput;
form.elements[3] = submitInput;
form.submit();

alert('after submit()'); // for debugging only
```

Comment: Shoot in the dark: set form to `display:none` and add it to an existing element in DOM and then submit it. I'd imagine that FF requires it to be in the DOM already.

Comment: @Balus: or even better, delete it after submit?

Comment: @JCOC: that's a non-concern for this specific issue :) Page will be refreshed anyway since OP doesn't use ajaxical stuff.

Comment: Yeah, that would go instead of `display:none`

Comment: @Balus - `document.body.appendChild(form);` worked. Thanks! If you want to put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @JCOC: I'd imagine that the reason of doing this in JS is just to hide the form from the enduser :) There may be some lag before the response returns. Hence the `display:none`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

FF requires it to be in the DOM already. Set form to `display:none` and add it to an existing element in DOM and then submit it.

Comment: Wouldn't this work too?  `document.body.appendChild(form);`  I'm honestly not too clear on distinct between "DOM" and "page" in this context.  Has similar issue where it worked fine in Chrome and failed in IE and FireFox.

Comment: `document` is root node of DOM tree.

Comment: Sorry for typos in last comment.  Wanted to make clear that while `document.createElement` doesn't add it to the DOM (like I'd assumed) it can still be accomplished programmatically with `appendChild`.  That is, it does not require the form be in the HTML markup when instantiated or anything like that.

Comment: Markup (retrieved HTML output) != DOM tree (client side model).

Answer (score 6):

Try This...

var idsInput = document.createElement('input');
idsInput.name = 'itemIds';
idsInput.value = ids;

var quantityInput = document.createElement('input');
quantityInput.name = 'quantity';
quantityInput.value = 1;

var authTokenInput = document.createElement('input');
authTokenInput.name = 'authenticityToken';
authTokenInput.value = '${session.getAuthenticityToken()}';

var submitInput = document.createElement('input');
submitInput.type = 'submit';
submitInput.value = 'anything';

var form = document.createElement('form');
form.action = '@{Checkout.setItemsQuantityHandler}';
form.method = 'POST';
form.elements[0] = idsInput;
form.elements[1] = quantityInput;
form.elements[2] = authTokenInput;
form.elements[3] = submitInput;
**document.body.appendChild(form);**
form.submit();